# Are P and N type materials in diode (once electrons have transferred) attracted by electrostatic attraction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Consider a P and N type material have exchanged electrons and holes. Assuming they could be perfectly separated but still are touching one another almost perfectly, will there be electrostatic attraction between the materials from the net positive vs net negative charge in either of them?